# How to specify mixed effect model in nlme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have been scouring Stackexchange and various sites for the past few days for an answer to this question, and I've found a lot of helpful comments. However, I want to know if I've used correct syntax for my model in `nlme`. A main issue is that I'm having trouble replicating published results from the exact same dataset. The experimental setup is as follows:

Randomized complete block design (i.e., 4 treatments [including control] within each block, 6 blocks)

Repeated measures (i.e., mean weekly measurements over the course of a year)

Unbalanced (i.e., sometimes weekly data is missing for some plots within blocks)

In the published work, the authors say that they used a "mixed model ANOVA with repeated measures and an autoregressive level 1 covariance matrix". They say that they use treatment, week, and their interaction as fixed effects and block as a random effect. Because of their specification of the covariance matrix structure, I have decided to use `nlme`, which allows for that parameter (as opposed to `lmer4`, as far as I understand). Here is my best attempt at replication, to no success:

```
mod <- lme(mean ~ treatment * week, random = ~ 1 | block/treatment, correlation = corAR1(), 
       control = lmeControl(opt = 'optim'), data = df)
```

I believe my issue lies somewhere in how I'm defining the "random" term. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What I can tell you is that your auto-correlation structure needs the same grouping factors as your random effect. You should also supply the time covariate to it if you have missing values. `corAR1(form = ~ week | block / treatment)`

Comment: @Roland - Thank you. I get this error when I use `week|block/treatment:`  `Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
  covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects`. This was my code: `mod <- lme(mean ~ treatment * week, random = ~ week | block/treatment, correlation = corAR1(value = 0.9, form = ~week|block/treatment), 
       control = lmeControl(opt = 'optim'), data = df)`

Comment: The error is self-explaining. Package nlme supports only one value per combination of week/block/treatment. If you have repeated measures inside this grouping, you can't use it. Do you have subplots? Or measurements twice a week? Or just random replicate measurments (which you'd need to aggregate then)?

Comment: @Roland - The error may be self-explaining, but it wasn't clear to me. As described in the post, this is a repeated measures experiment, where treatments within blocks were measured weekly. Because the weekly measurements are highly autocorrelated, that is why I'm using the correlation structure. I measured autocorrelation and input it into the parameter `value`. With this knowledge, do you see any other issues with the format of my code, based on what I want to accomplish?

Comment: Again, you have more than one measurement for a week on a block/treatment. You have not said that this can be expected.

Comment: @Ronald - I am not sure if I am interpreting you correctly, but no, there is not more than one measurement for a week on a treatment within a block (block/treatment). The block/treatment is the repeating unit. So I have treatment 1 within block 1...it is measured every week for a year. I also have treatment 2 within block 1, and it is also measured every week for a year. I also have treatment 1 in block 2, and it is measured every week for a year, and treatment 2 in block 2 measured every week for a year. Does this clarify? If it does, does my syntax look correct?

Comment: Check again.The error message doesn't lie.